# SCP Permission denied (publickey) - EC2 instance with bitnami magento

Tags: magento, amazon-ec2, debian, scp, bitnami

I'm running this command:

sudo scp -r -i /Users/Name/Desktop/Vue-storefront /Users/Name/Desktop/Directory/Magento\ key/pem/mykey.pem bitnami@ip:/opt/bitnami/apps

and then I'm getting this:

```
Load key "/Users/Name/Desktop/Vue-storefront": Is a directory
bitnami@ip: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

I've read through at least 20 or some posts on stackoverflow and everywhere else about this issue. I'm running mac terminal and I'm trying to copy a folder from my desktop to my server. I'm running an EC2 instance with bitnami magento.

1. Did "touch directory/directory/destination" on both local folder and server destination folder, checks out fine.
2. I have given correct permission to pem file (400) so don't have any problems ssh at all.
3. Itching my ass over this as I can't quite determine if I'm using wrong username? "user@ipadress". When I try to do scp, If username is bitnami@ipaddress and works fine when ssh, why wouldn't it be working when SCP? (I read something about this on stackoverflow not sure if it's correct).
4. I have also tried given both local folder 777 permissions as well as destination folder, I've tried sudo chmod +x and sudo chmod -R and about every chmod command I can think of and have read about in order to give right permissions. Still I am getting Permission denied (publickey).
5. I have added my id_rsa.pub key to /home/bitnami/.ssh/authorized_keys. (Copy and paste).
6. I have also manually typed in the command, directory etc so that there's no formatting fault.

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: `Load key "/Users/Name/Desktop/Vue-storefront": Is a directory` Is /Users/Name/Desktop/Vue-storefront a directory or a file?

Comment: Directory, any ideas?

Comment: A little update, so I ran this command: scp bitnami@ipadress:/Users/name/Desktop/Vue-storefront/* /opt/bitnami/apps

And got this: Enter passphrase for key '/Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa': 
scp: /Users/name/Desktop/Vue-storefront/*: No such file or directory

Have tried without " * " and with, without " ~ " and with to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question (The amount of adrenaline I got when I solved it is unexplainable as I've been spending countless of hours on this).

So for anyone coming from Google and are using mac, and find themselves in the same situation as me, make sure you have done what I've done and then use this command:

scp -r /Users/yourname/Desktop/Vue-storefront name@ipnumber:/opt/bitnami/apps

Notice before you do anything: Make sure you have generated a public key which is also on your server by typing in the terminal: ssh-keygen -t rsa

Then you can copy the output content where it starts with ssh-rsa inside your id_rsa.pub by using command cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Then you have to enter this command nano home/bitnami/.ssh/authorized_keys and enter in the copied content on the second line.

The logic I experimented with was that you scp -r your folder and then it's going to be copied over to your server (name@ipnumber) and the folder location of this follows after with (root/directory/folder) on my mac terminal.

Great start on my Friday!